# An error occurred in the Server Components render

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

[Error screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLGFa.png)I have weird error only in production. There isn't additional information, I suspect due security in production.
And I can't detect it in development mode.
Please help, I'll provide any possible information if you need!

Comment: It would help if you give some context and code.

Comment: Just the project has a huge ecosystem, page with this error has a lot of depended part, at list a can't share it due NDA, and even if I could, I just haven't any ideas what could I share
I guess that's more about Next.js working concept
And I'm looking for people which met the same issue, or just has ideas about possible origins

Comment: In that case what about trial and error. Start empty and add pieces of code to identify when the error occurs.

Comment: Well, yes, this is one of possible ways for now 
Just maybe will found somebody else who got the same error. It could be helpful.
This error occurs, when user stay on the page ~20^ minutes, so I suspected that it could be some browser safe mode, like chrome safe battery mode, so as temporary solution, I have set hard page reload (not with router.refresh())

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the fetching failed because the server components are trying to fetch from the API route but routes don't exist. Because during build process there are no API routes.

I think you should deploy without API route first, then once you server is up, you can modify you code to use API route and deploy again.

Comment: the fact in that I do not use API routes, or did I understood wrong what do you mean? I guess you talked about Next API routes , like `/api/myroute/route.ts` ??